# usage of observableCollection in longlistselector

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, observablecollection, longlistselector

I am using the _wordItems as the longlistselector's itemsource in order to dynamically delete items in longlistSelector

```
private ObservableCollection<Group<WordItem>> _wordItems = new ObservableCollection<Group<WordItem>>();
```

The Group class is defined as:

```
public class Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public Group(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.Key = name;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            this.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Group<T> that = obj as Group<T>;
        return (that != null) && (this.Key.Equals(that.Key));
    }

    public string Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and the WordItem class is defined as:

```
[Table]
public class WordItem //:INotifyPropertyChanged,INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private int _wordItemId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int WordItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _wordItemId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_wordItemId != value)
            {
                _wordItemId = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private string _word;
    [Column(CanBeNull=false)]
    public string Word
    {
        get
        {
            return _word;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_word != value)
            {
                _word = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private string _wordExplains;
    [Column]
    public string WordExplains
    {
        get
        {
            return _wordExplains;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_wordExplains != value)
            {
                _wordExplains = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I use the code `_wordItems[1].RemoveAt(1);`, the _wordItems has been modified, and the longlistselector in the screen has also deleted certain item. But the problem is that when I call `_wordItems[1].RemoveAt(1);`, the longlistselector just deleted the `_wordItems[1][0]` item. When I call `_wordItems[1].RemoveAt(0);`, it just deleted the header of the second group and combined the items in `_worditems[1]` with the `_wordItem[0]`.

The definition of longlistselector:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="WordsGroup" Background="Transparent"
                                              Margin="12,0,12,73" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WordItemTemplate}"
                                              GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource YoudaoGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                                              GroupItemTemplate="{StaticResource YoudaoGroupItemTemplate}" 
                                              SelectionChanged="WordsGroup_SelectionChanged"
                                              >
                        <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
                    </toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

The datatemplate is as:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="WordItemTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,3,0,5">
                <StackPanel >
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu Opened="ContextMenu_Opened" >
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="delete this word" Click="DelectWord_Click"/>
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="share this word" Click="SMSShare_Click"/>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WordItemId}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Word}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding WordExplains}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"  Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="YoudaoGroupHeaderTemplate">
            <Border Background="#1BA1E2" Margin="0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="30" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="YoudaoGroupItemTemplate" >
            <Border Background="#1BA1E2" Width="99" Height="99" Margin="6">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**Thx in advance.**

ps. I am using the linq as

```
var wordBy4sLetter = from word in wordList
                                         group word by word.Word.ToCharArray()[0].ToString() into s
                                         orderby s.Key
                                         select new Group<WordItem>(s.Key, s);
this._wordItems = wordBy4sLetter.ToObservableCollection();
                        this.WordsGroup.ItemsSource = this._wordItems;
```

Comment: hi, Richard, any thoughts about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another ObservableCollection. Take a look at the accepted answer for this question. [Group Listbox for Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624189/group-listbox-for-windows-phone-7)

I have modified the code there and created new Add/Remove methods that will create a group if not there for an add, and remove the group if it's empty on a remove.

Comment: I've downloaded the "TVGuide" project, finding it a awesome Windows phone app, but I just got confused. It's a little too complex for me to understand the usage of the LongListCollection class. Any other thoughts about the reason why the Longlistselector UI removed the wrong item? Thx.